# Remove Rows with Special Characters using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted remove Row (0) if it contains dotted lines it. If the Row (0) doesn't contain dotted lines, then don't make any changes. What is the right way to do it?

```
df.iloc[0]

Status                                  --------------------
First_Name                               ------------------------------
Last_Name                       ------------------------------
Phone                         ------------------------------
Address                     -------------------------------
Email                                                    -------
Task                                          ------------
Growth                        -------------------------------
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas' `str` methods, but know that they only work one column at a time so you will need to apply across rows.

```
cols = ['Status', 'First_Name'] # desire columns you want to check

df = df[~df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('-')).any(axis=1)]
```